# C++'s max() with initializer list returns strings out of order

Tags: c++, string, c++11, max, initializer-list

```
max({"a", "b", "z", "x"});  returns "x"
```

while both

```
max<std::string>({"a", "b", "z", "x"});
```

and

```
max({'a', 'b', 'z', 'x'});
```

return "z" as they should. Why?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`"a"`, `"b"` etc. are string literals. These decay to `const char*` when in the initializer list. `max` <strike>just</strike> probably gets the one with the highest address, but since it uses `operator<` to compare them, and they aren't part of the same array, or one-past the same array, the result of the comparison is unspecified (and the invocation of `max` would result in *undefined behaviour*, since the requirement is that the type be [`LessThanComparable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/LessThanComparable)).

The other two invocations of `max` are well defined. `char`s such as `a`, `b` etc. are integral types with a well defined less-than comparison. And `std::string` has an `operator<` that implements a lexicographical comparison.

Comment: The result of the comparison is unspecified, not undefined.

Comment: @T.C. Do you have the reference for that? I guess if it were unspecified, it would still make an invocation under `max` undefined, by virtue of not providing a strict weak ordering.

Comment: Last sentence of [expr.rel]/p4. Good point about the strict weak ordering, though.

Answer (score 12):

`max({"a", "b", "z", "x"});` attempts to compare pointers. This has undefined behaviour (since the results of the individual comparisons are unspecified). It you wanted to compare pointers, you should write:

```
std::max({"a", "b", "z", "x"}, std::less<const char*>());
```

By contrast, `max({'a', 'b', 'z', 'x'});` compares integral values, and `max<std::string>` compares strings.

Comment: Why is the behaviour undefined?

Comment: @P45Imminent: The `<` operator for pointer operands is only defined for pointers to subobjects of the same common object.

Comment: My memory fails me. Is it OK to compare to one past the end of an array? I have boldly stated that in my answer but now I'm not so sure.

Comment: @juanchopanza Yes. [expr.rel] "If one pointer points to an element of an array, or to a subobject thereof, and another pointer points
one past the last element of the array, the latter pointer compares greater"

Comment: @juanchopanza: Yes, I forgot to say that in my comment. The comment was kind of tailored to the situation in the question. Sorry :-S

Comment: Sometimes SO produces really good questions for interview. Much better than anything i've seen or heard of.

Comment: "I[f] you wanted to compare pointers, you should write: ..."  Isn't that _still_ undefined behavior?  You're just more explicitly comparing pointers to separate objects.

Comment: The result of the comparison is unspecified, not undefined.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy No, specializations of `std::less` and friends for pointer types are guaranteed to yield a total order, even if the corresponding built-in operators don't

Comment: @T.C.: You're right! This is one of the rare cases where C++ is laxer than C (it's UB in C). I believe C++ had to make this defined in order to accommodate `constexpr` (which is required to detect UB).

Comment: @P45Imminent: See the recent comments; the comparison itself is not UB in C++11 and later, only unspecified. I confused it with pointer comparison in C, which is UB.

Comment: @KerrekSB I don't think it's `constexpr` - it's unspecified in C++03, too. Also, `constexpr` must diagnose unspecified pointer comparisons - see [expr.const]/p2 (third-to-last bullet in N3337, bullet 2.19 in N4140)